# JavaScript Associate Array access returns "literal" Array Prototype Code

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

Here is my code so far for my school project (using *Murach's JavaScript and DOM Scripting by Ray Harris*). The chapter is only about Arrays and does not cover Prototypes, but I wanted to try it out based on Internet tutorials and references:

```
 /*
Operation

    This application stores the last name, first name, and score for 
    one or more students and it calculates the average score for all of the scores
    that have been entered. When the user clicks on the Clear button, this 
    application clears the score data from this application. When the user clicks 
    on the Sort button, this application sorts the data in alphabetical order by 
    last name.

Specifications

    The program should use one or more arrays to store the data.
    Assume that the user will enter valid data.
*/
var $ = function (id) 
{ 
    return document.getElementById(id); 
}

/*
Array prototype object extension for averaging the contents

"Adding a method to the built-in Array object to extract the average 
of any numerical values stored in the array is therefore a useful 
addition to that object." http://javascript.about.com/library/blaravg.htm
*/
Array.prototype.average = function () 
{
    var avg = 0;
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i<this.length; i++) 
    {
       //never gets here:
        alert(i + ": " + this[i]);
        var e = +this[i];
        if(!e && this[i] !== 0 && this[i] !== '0') 
        {
            e--;
        }
        if (this[i] == e) 
        {
            avg += e;
            count++;
        }
    }   
    return avg / count;
}

var addScore = function ()
{
    studentScores[$('last_name').value + ', ' + $('first_name').value] = $('score').value;
    update();
}

var clearScore = function ()
{
    for (var i in studentScores)
    {
        studentScores[i] = '';
    }
    update();
}

var sortScore = function ()
{
    scores.sort();
    update();
}

var update = function ()
{
    var result = '';
    for (var i in studentScores)
    {
        result += (i + ': ' + studentScores[i] + '\n');
    }
    $('scores').value = result;
    $('average_score').value = studentScores.average().toFixed(1);
}

window.onload = function ()
{
    //a variable is initialized inside a function without var, it will have a global scope:
    studentScores = [];
    $('add_button').onclick = addScore;
    $('sort_button').onclick = sortScore;
    $('clear_button').onclick = clearScore;
    $('last_name').focus();
}
```

When the code enters the "update()" function (end of the "addScore()" function) and accesses the array,
it populates the "literal" code from the Prototype into the text area (and fails to find the average on the next line):

I don't have enough rep points to post the image, but here is my output (there are no errors in the Chrome JS Console):

```
lowe, doug: 82
average: function () 
{
    var avg = 0;
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i<this.length; i++) 
    {
        //never gets here:
        alert(i + ": " + this[i]);
        var e = +this[i];
        if(!e && this[i] !== 0 && this[i] !== '0') 
        {
            e--;
        }
        if (this[i] == e) 
        {
            avg += e;
            count++;
        }
    }   
    return avg / count;
}
```

Any help appreciated (best practice or algorithm suggestions welcome)

Comment: When do you actually call `output`?

Comment: What `output()` function, and what array?

Comment: Whoops... "update()" function is what I meant to say, question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
studentScores = []
```

to this:

```
studentScores = {}
```

...so that you're using an Object instead of an Array.

Your `for` loop in `average()` is just iterating numeric indices instead of the non-numeric keys you created.

Create your `average()` method as a standalone function like the others, and pass `studentScores` to it to calculate the average, and then use `for-in` instead of `for`.

Comment: You got exactly what I was going for and your solution worked- Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's simple: [Do not use `for…in` enumerations for looping Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays)! You do so in your `clearScore` and `update` functions.

`for (var prop in obj)` loops over all [enumerable] properties, including those that are inherited from `Array.prototype` (for Array objects at least). A `for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++)` loop will not have that problem.

Comment: Good advice, thanks. I ended up going with `for...in` because I wanted to use an Associate Array (correctly)

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide whether studentScores is intended to be an array (i.e., an integer is used to access the stored data) or an Object/Associative Array (a string is used to set/get an element).

If you want to use the student's name as the key, you should declare studentScores as an object, and your 'average' method would have to be added to the Object prototype (which I don't recommend).

With the current state of the code, you have stumbled on the fact that an Array is also an object, and can have arbitrary properties attached to it, like any other object.  You have added properties by name, but in your average method, you are trying to access numerically based indices.  But that's not where the data you're adding is stored.

```
> a = [];
[]
> a['foo'] = 'bar';
'bar'
> a.length
0
> a[3] = 0;
0
> a.length
4
```

Comment: "Object/Associate Array" - Thanks for your helpful explanation of the Object vs. Array indices with examples